# How do I show that :$\sigma({p^m})$ is divisible by $4$ if $m=4k+1$ , and $k$ is an integer number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

How do i show this if it's not an open problem :$\sigma({p^m})$ is divisible by $4$ if $m=4k+1$ , and $k$ is an integer number and p is prime number.
and $\sigma({p^m})$ is sum divisors of $p^m$

*Attempt* :$σ({p}^{4l}−1) = ({p}^{4m}−1)/(p − 1)$. Write $p^m = q$ so that

this is $(q^2 + 1)(q + 1)$and both factors are even. !!!!!!

Note : I have tried to proof it using some results in number theory about divisibilty but sorry i can't succed

Thank you for any help.

Comment: p should be odd?

Comment: may you meant p>2  ?

Comment: I didnt made any exclusive for p in my question

Comment: if m = 5 then the divisors of $p^5$ are $1, p, p^2, p^3, p^4, p^5$  if p is congruent to -1 mod 4 then these do sum to 0 mod 4 but if p is 1 mod 4 then they sum to 2.

Comment: Hold on, standard use writes, I believe, $\sigma(n)$ for the sum of the divisors of n.  Did you mean something different?

Comment: If $m$ is of the shape $4k+3$ and $p$ is an odd prime then $\sigma(p^m)$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas sure, but the OP specified m = 4k+1.

Comment: Well, OP is wrong for $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  Understood.  And p must be odd.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, i edited the question i have added my attempt but i'm not sure if it is true

Comment: I do not understand, it would be (if $m=4k+1$) $\frac{p^{4k+2}-1}{p-1}$. But the result fails, as a  counterexample in the comment shows, It is easier to work with the expression $1+p+\cdots +p^m$ than with the expression we get from the sum of a geometric series formula.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of divisors of $p^m$ is
$$
\sigma(p^m) = 1 + p + p^2 + \ldots + p^m.
$$
Any odd prime number have form $p=4q+1$ or $p=4q-1$. Ok, if $p=4q+1$, then
$$
\sigma(p^m)\equiv 1 + 1 + \ldots + 1 = m+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 4\Longrightarrow m = 4k-1.
$$
If $p=4q-1$, then
$$
\sigma(p^m)\equiv 1 - 1 + 1 + \ldots + (-1)^m = \begin{cases}0,& \text{$m$ is odd}\\1,&\text{$m$ is even}\end{cases} \pmod 4,
$$
and $m=2k$.

Comment: There seem to be something wrong. You conclude $m=4k - 1$... it should be $m=4k+1$

Comment: @johannesvalks, $p=5$, $m=3$, $\sigma(5^3) = 1 + 5 + 25 + 125 = 156 = 4 \cdot 39$

Comment: Indeed. My bad mistake...